# devtools::load_all() "cannot find function x" when function x is part of a loaded package

Tags: r, devtools

I've been getting this error message recently:

```
> load_all(file.path(.db,"R-projects","taRifx.geo"))
Loading taRifx.geo
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "Polygons"
```

Where that folder is my local copy of: https://github.com/gsk3/taRifx.geo

`Polygons` is part of `sp`, and `sp` is loaded:

```
> Polygons
function (srl, ID) 
{
    stopifnot(is.list(srl))
    stopifnot(length(srl) > 0)
    if (any(sapply(srl, function(x) !is(x, "Polygon")))) 
        stop("srl not a list of Polygon objects")
    if (missing(ID)) 
        stop("Single ID required")
    if (length(ID) != 1) 
        stop("Single ID required")
    ID <- as.character(ID)
    stopifnot(nchar(ID) > 0)
    res <- .Call(Polygons_c, srl, ID)
    res
}
<environment: namespace:sp>
```

`sp` is also in the package's `Depends` section in `DESCRIPTION`.

Is there a weird scoping thing that is preventing `load_all` from seeing `Polygons` at the time it is loading the package?  If so, how do I diagnose/fix?

Comment: Try `load_all("taRifx.geo", reset=FALSE)`. Not sure why it works, so I can't completely vouch for it, but it does seem to do the trick.

Comment: Could you then please either remove the question or post the solution ?

Comment: Thanks for re-upping this Karl.  It doesn't work consistently.  I'll post my kludge for now (basically running it twice).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the first time you load it, it fails (but loads the dependency), so then waiting a second and trying again has consistently worked for me:

```
try( load_all("taRifx.geo",reset=FALSE) )
Sys.sleep(1)
try( load_all("taRifx.geo",reset=FALSE) )
```

Not sure the `reset=FALSE` is entirely necessary.